# Type 'System.Web.HttpRequest' cannot be serialized

Tags: wcf, serialization, upload, httprequest

I am trying to design an Picture Upload feature into a web site.
I am using ASP.NET 3.5, C#, and WCF.

I have been asked to accomplish the following:

1) Make the Uploader a Web Service 
2) Return progress updates to the user as files are uploaded. 
3) Log other relevant user-selected options in the database.

So, I have started off by creating a WCF web client with the 
below service contract:

```
IService.UploadPictures(HttpRequest request);

private UploadServiceClient upload;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

      upload = new UploadServiceClient();
      upload.UploadPictures(Request.Files);

}
```

When I compile, I get the below error:

> Type 'System.Web.HttpRequest' cannot
>   be serialized. Consider marking it
>   with the DataContractAttribute, and
>   marking all of its members you want
>   serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.

So, I went back into my service contract and 
changed [OperationContract] to [DataContract]
but the change produced the same error.

Can somebody kindly tell me what I am doing wrong
and provide examples as to how to best move forward?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use something like a HttpRequest as a WCF parameter. The error messages says it all - the HttpRequest is not serializable, and in order to work with WCF, types have to be serializable.

Also, you need to remember: you're not just passing an object instance to a method here - what you're really doing is having the WCF runtime serialize your request (the method name to call plus all the parameters passed in) into a message (think: e-mail or xml file), sending it to the server, deserialising there and building up a new copy of the given datatype (as defined in your DataContract), and doing something with it.

Your WCF service could well be self-hosted, e.g. running in a NT Service or console app - no HttpRequest available in those circumstances!

You need to definitely rearchitect your solution - you need to either check into WCF streaming to upload files to WCF (google for it - you'll find plenty of hits) or you'll need to find another way to pass the relevant info (e.g. list of filenames) to the WCF service without use of a HttpRequest object.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting a request as a parameter to a request.  This is not what you want to do.  I'm assuming that "Request.Files" is an array of files.  This is what you want to upload.  So something like:

```
IService.UploadPictures(List<SomeFileType> request);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick (and apologies for the delay). 

That makes sense and has given me something to work with.

I have a related question. I understand how to do this once the upload posts to the server, but is it possible to do this as a client WCF callback? In other words, how do I pass the parameter request of type "List<SomeFileType>" when I am calling the method from the client (../upload.svc/uploadpictures/param)?

My logic is that I want to poll using JavaScript (via IFrame) and it seems easier to me to handle everything via a single JS method. 

Thanks again.