# Type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' cannot be serialized

Tags: wcf, upload, stream, serialization

I have been trying to design a WCF file upload service and am getting the following error
in my web application:

> Type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported
>   types.

Based on this error, I have tried re-marking my FileTransfer
class with DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute
but that didn't do anything:

```
[DataContractAttribute(Namespace = "FileTransfer")]
public class FileTransfer
{
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string GetUploadStatus;
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public Tuple<string, int> DoUpload;
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public int UploadFile;
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public FileTransferInfo FileInfo;
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public Stream FileByteStream;
}
```

I have tried accessing my Service Trace Log with Service Trace Viewer to 
see if I could get some more detail on this error. I found a number of errors
with the following message:

> The message with To
>   'http://localhost:1242/WebProj/filetransfer.svc/mex/mex'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver,
>   due to an AddressFilter mismatch at
>   the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that
>   the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree.

Which would have been useful to me but I also found the same error for:

> 'http://localhost:1242/WebProj/auth.svc/mex/mex'

in the same trace and I was able to authenticate just fine without any errors which made me wonder if this error is something that I should be worrying about (if any body has a suggestion as to why there is a mex/mex at my endpoint, that would be great).

So, why can't 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' be serialized? I have provided the other important aspects of my code below. Maybe somebody out there can see something that I have missed?

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "FileTransfer")]
public class FileTransferInfo
{
    private string _guid;
    private int _flag;
    private long _fileSize;
    private string _fileName;
    private DateTime _lastUpdate;
    private FileTypeEnum _fileType;

    //REMOVED GETTERS AND SETTERS FOR SPACE 

 }

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "FileTransfer")]
public interface IFileTransferService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "DoUpload")]
    Tuple<string, int> DoUpload(List<FileTransferInfo> request);

    [OperationContract(Action="UploadFile", Name="UploadFile")]
    int UploadFile(FileTransfer request);

}
```

Here is my UploadFile method that is returning the error.

```
int IFileTransferService.UploadFile(FileTransfer request)
{

    string uploadFolder = @"C:\TempMultiFileUploads\";
    int errCode = default(int);
    // parameters validation omitted for clarity
   try 
   {
        string filename = request.FileInfo.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, filename);

        using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            const int bufferSize = 65536; // 64K

            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                outfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = request.FileByteStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        //System.IOException
        errCode = 800;
    }

   return errCode;

} 
    And, below is the endpoint, binding, and bahavior of my FileTransferService:

<endpoint name="MyFileTransferEP"
          address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpEPBehavior"
          bindingConfiguration="httpLargeDataStream"
          contract="FileTransfer.IFileTransferService" />   

<binding name="httpLargeDataStream" 
               closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
               openTimeout="00:01:00"
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
               sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
               maxBufferSize="65536"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
               messageEncoding="Mtom"
               transferMode="StreamedRequest">        

<behavior name="BasicHttpEPBehavior">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
</behavior>
```

Here is the code in my web application that calls the upload method:

```
FileTransferServiceClient upload = new FileTransferServiceClient();
HttpPostedFile m_objFile = default(HttpPostedFile);
FileTransfer transmit = new FileTransfer();

transmit.FileByteStream = m_objFile.InputStream;
transmit.FileInfo = new FileTransferInfo();
transmit.FileInfo.Guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
transmit.FileInfo.Flag = default(int);
transmit.FileInfo.FileSize = m_objFile.ContentLength;
transmit.FileInfo.FileName = m_objFile.FileName;
transmit.FileInfo.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

int retParam = upload.UploadFile(transmit); // THROWS ERROR HERE
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580639/type-system-web-httprequest-cannot-be-serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define a data contract with a Stream member. You can either take or return a Stream as single parameter or define a message contract which has a single MessageBodyMember of type Stream, but can have multiple MessageHeaders. For more on large data streaming in WCF, please refer to [this section of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: I have a related follow-up error if you don't mind:
<br>
Error 3 The type 'WebAPI.FileTransfer.FileUploadMessage' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\web-06.08.09\8a531a06\51fdee26\assembly\dl3\ae1f49ea\c2031a0d_1758ca01\WebAPILibrary.DLL' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\web-06.08.09\8a531a06\51fdee26\App_WebReferences.7bmoffs1.dll' 
<br>
I am pretty sure I am not repeating assemblies & have cleared ASP.NET TEMP. I have also deleted my service and re-added it. Any ideas what I might be doing here?

Comment: You have a web reference *and* you appear to referencing a pre-compiled data contract assembly (WebAPILibrary) with the same namespace/type name in it. Delete your web reference if you're going to reference an external assembly.