# Type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

The problem I am facing is that when I try to upload a `byte[]` to *Azure* blob storage I receive the following exception:

> Error: Type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' in Assembly 'System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

I therefore went about marking the Class in which the code resides with     `[Serializable]` but still the same exception is raised.

Upload.aspx.cs:

```
[Serializable]
    public partial class Upload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            HttpPostedFile filePosted = Request.Files["File1"];
            string fn = Path.GetFileName(filePosted.FileName);
            try
            {                 
                byte[] bytes = ObjectToByteArray(filePosted.InputStream);
                Share[] shares = f.split(bytes);
                UploadImageServiceClient client = new UploadImageServiceClient();
                client.Open();
                foreach (Share share in shares)
                {
                    byte[] serialized = share.serialize();
                    Response.Write("Processing upload...");
                    client.UploadImage(serialized);
                }
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
      }
}
```

I know there are similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632258/type-system-web-httpinputstream-cannot-be-serialized) which explain that you cannot define a data contract with a Stream member but my WCF Cloud service does not feature a Stream or FileStream member.

Here is my WCF service implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadImageService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void UploadImage(byte[] bytes);
}
```

And my service is as follows:

```
public void UploadImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
      CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(connString));
    // Create the blob client.
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
    // Retrieve reference to a blob passed in as argument.
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("sample");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    try
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    catch (StorageException ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to serialize the entire stream object here :

`byte[] bytes = ObjectToByteArray(filePosted.InputStream);`

you should probably just copy the bytes out of the stream into a `byte[]` and submit that.

Here is a quick example using a memory stream:

```
        byte[] bytes; // you'll upload this byte array after you populate it.
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["File1"];
        using (var mS = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(mS);
            bytes = mS.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: thanks I had to change a couple of other things to get exactly what I wanted but your answer did eradicate the exception I was receiving